# Multiple Classes Read From Single Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project which requires to start a `Timer` on load of the `Form1` that  increments the `TimerCount` Property of Class `TimeCounter` in the tick event.

The Project has also `Form2` which when open I want to read the increment updates from `TimeCounter` class which is being incremented by the `Form1` because `Form1` is parent and will not close I tried to read from `TimeCounter` but got default set value which is 0.

Here is code:

**Timer Class**

```
public class TimeCounter
{
    public int timer=0;
    public int TimerCount { get; set; }

    public int  GetTime()
    {        
        return timer;           
    }
}
```

**Form1 Increment TimerCount After 1 Second**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    sk++;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.TimerCount = sk;

}
```

**Form2 Which Receive Counter Continuously(But Not Working)**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      timer.Interval = 1000;
      timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
      timer.Enabled = true;
      timer.Start();
  }

  void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
      Timer t1 = new Timer();
      B01CountDown.Text = t1.GetTime().ToString();           
  }
```

Comment: How can anything in your code work?? you are initializing the Timer t  whenever timer elapses. Check my answer

Comment: Abhishek what is the solution?

Comment: Why is `Form1_Load` in form 2? Copy and paste error?

Comment: where from you open `Form2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `Timer` object correctly to Form2. You need to pass the instance of `Timer` being used by form 1 to form 2.

Timer:

```
public class Timer
{
    public int timer = 0;
    public int TimerCount { get; set; }

    public int GetTime()
    {

        return timer;

    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.TimerCount++;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(_timer);
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Timer _timer;

    public Form2(Timer timer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = timer;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = _timer.TimerCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: You will get a cross-thread exception as you cant update label in the tick event

Comment: @Abhishek no you will not. See the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Alot Ephraim.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code you have posted as follows. If you do not understand, then you need to start learning C#.

**TimeCounter:**

```
public class TimeCounter
{
    public static int timer = 0;
    public static int TimerCount 
    { 
        get
        {
            return timer;
        }
        set
        {
            timer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeCounter.TimerCount++;
    }        
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (B01CountDown.InvokeRequired)
        {
            B01CountDown.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                B01CountDown.Text = TimeCounter.TimerCount.ToString();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a little problem the Form receive Counter late it goes 4 then 10 then 25 ...

Comment: That is because, 2 forms have 2 separate timers. As per your question what I understood was that you wanted to update the `TimerCount` variable in `TimeCounter` class and get that value in the timer tick event of the second timer in the second form.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't require `TimeCounter` Class and also `Timer` in `Form2`

see below code

---

> Form1

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int sk = 0;
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your Stuff
        sk++;
        form2.UpdateLabel(sk.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

> Form2

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateLabel(string Message)
    {
        if (B01CountDown.InvokeRequired)
        {
            B01CountDown.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                B01CountDown.Text = Message;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```